# For text match problem, what is the different between question-question match and question-answer match?

Tags: deep-learning, nlp

I know question-question match is a text similarity problem.

What about question-answer or question-doc match? It is used in information retrieval.

question-question match is indeed text similarity. But how do you define question-answer similarity?

Thank you!!

Comment: Assuming that the answer has more sentences than the single-lined question, there is always a sentence in the answer which shows more similarity with the sentence of the question. You can encode the question to a vector. Then one-by-one, encode each sentence of the answer into a vector. Take all the similarity scores and take the mean of them. This averaged score will represent the mean similarity of the answer with the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can refer to the paper "A Deep Look into Neural Ranking Models for
Information Retrieval" to get more discussion about different matching tasks.